# Is it possible for ffmpeg to encode with a spatially variable bit rate?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, bitrate

I would like to reduce the overall bitrate of a 4K 180 degree FOV video by decreasing detail outside of 60 degrees while retaining it in the center. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if it is possible with ffmpeg. With libx264 is is possible by setting quant_offsets, but I don't believe it is exposed on the command line, so you would need to do some coding.